# How to add a association in a association table from a controller with Entity Framework, C#, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm struggling with this question. I have created 2 tables with Entity Framework: `User` and `Project`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace COBRA.Models.DBClass
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Nom { get; set; }
        public string? Prenom { get; set; }
        public string? Societe { get; set; }
        [EnumDataType(typeof(Metiers))]
        public Metiers Metier { get; set; }

        public enum Metiers
        {
            Macon = 0,
            Electricien = 1,
            Ingenieur = 2,
            Charpentier = 3,
            Carreleur = 4
        }
        public ICollection<Projet>? Projets { get; set; }
    }

    public class Projet
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Nom { get; set; }
        public string? Historique { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreation { get; set; }
        [EnumDataType(typeof(Status))]
        public Status ProjetStatus { get; set; }

        public enum Status
        {
            EnCours = 0,
            Fini = 1,
        }

        public int IDSysteme { get; set; }
        public ICollection<User>? Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Entity Framework creates an association table: `UserProjet`.

But I have no clue how to add values in this association table from a controller like `ProjetsController` for example.

I have an action to list specific `projet` for a `User` (with his id):

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetProjetsByUser(int? id)
    {
        return View("Index", await _context.Projets
            .Where(c => c.Users
            .Any(s => s.Id.Equals(id)))
            .ToListAsync());
    }
```

But, how add a new association?

Sorry for my English - and thank you for your time

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

Comment: I'm using SQL Server for the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because according your class structure you request a many-to-many relationship. Within user you have a collection of projets and within projet you have a collection of users. Therefore EF creates an interconnected table with a reference to user and another to projet

For more information head over to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?#many-to-many

For coding simplicity you can even create the interconnected table by yourself

```
public class UserProjet
{
    public Projet Projet{get;set;}
    public User User{get;set;}
}
```

reference the UserProjet as ICollection in Projet and User class and define a DbSet within the DbContext class. Then you can easily call the usual Add,Remove,... methods.

Otherwise, without the above mentioned code, by adding a User to the users collection on a projet object will create the needed objects into the UserProj table

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I was thinking => adding an element to the collection but I'm not sure I'm on the right path:
```
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddProjectToUser(int? id)
        {
            ICollection<User> XUser = _context.Projets.Select(x => x.Users);
            XUser.Add(new User);
```
Thank a lot